# Copy highlighted code into clipboard in jekyll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

I am creating a blog using jekyll. I am using prettyprint to highlight the code snippets. I have written a jquery to display a button on hover of the code snippet (inside <pre> tag). On the button click I am getting the entire html of the code snippet but I want to copy the pure text of the code snippet.

Can someone please advise me how to achieve this?

Comment: After googling a while, I got a plugin called ZeroClipboard. This does exactly what I want. 
Demo is given here: http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/

The integration process is given here
https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md

Alternatively this URL will help:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jquery-copy-clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`document.execCommand` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) can be used to copy text to the clipboard in JavaScript. jQuery is not required.

```js
function copy() {
  var element = document.getElementById('input');

  element.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  element.blur();
}
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<button onclick="copy()">Copy Text</button>
```